# How to perform common FB actions using Meteor?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, meteor

What are the steps required to perform common Facebook actions in Meteor, using the `accounts-facebook` package? I'm trying to get a friends list, post on a wall, and eventually perform other actions, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: Slight modifications for meteor 0.6.0

You need to use an API to help you such as the nodefacebook graph api: https://github.com/criso/fbgraph

You would need to make a package. You need to make a directory called `/packages` and in that a directory called `fbgraph`.

Each package needs a `package.js` (placed in the fbgraph directory). In your `package.js` you can use something like:

```
Package.describe({
    summary: "Facebook fbgraph npm module",
});

Package.on_use(function (api) {
    api.add_files('server.js', 'server');
});

Npm.depends({fbgraph:"0.2.6"});
```

**server side js - server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'postToFacebok':function(text) {
        var graph = Npm.require('fbgraph');
        if(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken) {
          graph.setAccessToken(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
          var future = new Future();
          var onComplete = future.resolver();
          //Async Meteor (help from : https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021
          graph.post('/me/feed',{message:text},function(err,result) {
              return onComplete(err, result);
          }
          Future.wait(future);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Then while logged in on the client

**Client side js**

```
Meteor.call("postToFacebook", "Im posting to my wall!", function(err,result) {
    if(!err) alert("Posted to facebook");
});
```

Fbgraph repo : https://github.com/criso/fbgraph

Graph API docs for list of requests: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Async (To wait for the callback from facebook before returning data to the client): https://gist.github.com/possibilities/3443021

Comment: I believe about a day after you answered this, Meteor 0.6.0 was released, allowing us to declare dependencies on NPM modules (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#v060). I'm curious as to what that would look like for this example, rather than installing it directly into `.meteor`

Comment: I made a couple of updates showing how to use this in Meteor 0.6.0+. Npm modules need to be declared in packages.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Did this actually work for you? `Npm.require('fbgraph')` simply returns `undefined` for me, even though I can see that the `fbgraph` module is present in my project and no exceptions have been thrown.

Comment: You have to use Npm.depends first. it's not installable via `npm install`

Comment: Yes, that's what I used in my package.js. My example looks quite similar to yours. I may be able to post a gist later tonight.