# How does Meteor methods return results?

Tags: reactjs, facebook-graph-api, meteor

I am using meteor/react for learning facebook graph api. 
I want to access users' post on facebook timeline and display them on screen. How can that be done?

With the guidance of the solution provided here [[How to perform common FB actions using Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788459/how-to-perform-common-fb-actions-using-meteor?answertab=active#tab-top]). I have tried the following code: server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
'seePost' : function(){
  var graph=Npm.require('fbgraph');
  if(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken){
    graph.setAccessToken(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
    var future = new Future();
    var onComplete = future.resolver();
    graph.get('/me/feed',function(err,result) {
            console.log(result);
            return onComplete(err,result);
    })
   Future.wait(future);
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }

}
});
```

client side code :
    `Meteor.call("seePost", function(err,result) {
        if(err) console.log("error" , err);
        else console.log("RES", result);
        });`

I expect the result displayed in the client side console since I want to show the users the posts on his/er timeline, But I get following output :
RES, undefined

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `await` and `Meteor.callAsync`

Basically the client code waits for the call to complete, and gives you the returned data

```
const result = await Meteor.callAsync("seePost");
```

Errors should be handled with a try..catch block

Comment: The function that it appears in must be declared with `async`, such as `async function myFunction()`

Answer (score 1):

If you use fibers/future, you need to return something with "future".

```
const future = new Future();
// some code getting result or something 
future.return(something);
return future.wait();
```

this will return something in the callback from client call.

Answer (score 1):

try this code, when you're using fibers you need to "wait" for the response

```
Meteor.methods({
  'seePost': function () {
    var graph = Npm.require('fbgraph');
    if (Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken) {
      graph.setAccessToken(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
      var future = new Future();
      var onComplete = future.resolver();
      graph.get('/me/feed', function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (err) {
          return future.return(false);
        } else {
          return future.return(result);
        }
      })
      return future.wait();
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```